# Extract all commits related to a file and use this to build a new repo

Tags: git, commit

I have a bunch of independent scripts in my git repository. The repo has a lot of commits now with each commit relating to one or more of the scripts. Now, I want to move one of these scripts to a repository of its own. To achieve my goal, I would need to proceed in two steps.

- Identify the commits related to the required script
- Somehow combine these commits to a new repo

To achieve the first goal, I can just run `git log -p filename` and get the patches. But, once I get the patches, I am not able to figure out how to combine them into a new repository.

Comment: What should be done with commits that also change different files in addition to the file you are interested in?

Comment: Hopefully extract changes related only to the file I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3):

So, here's one way to do it.  Start by creating a copy of your repository:

```
git clone myrepo myrepo_work
```

Now, change into the copy, because we are going to edit the heck out of the history:

```
cd myrepo_work
```

Let's say you want to isolate changes to the script `myscript.sh`.  We're going to filter the history of the repository, removing everything that *is not* that file:

```
git filter-branch \
  --prune-empty \
  --tree-filter 'rm -rf $(ls | grep -v myscript.sh)'
  master
```

This will iterate over every commit in the history of your repository, running our little shell script against the checked out files for that commit.  The `--prune-empty` option means that commits that contain no files are removed from your history.

Comment: I suggest using `find -not -path ./myscript.sh -delete` as the filter command to avoid all edge cases (like a second file of that name in a subdirectory, or a file name that contains the file name you are looking for as a substring).

Comment: @larsks: I can see the logic in your approach. But, when I run the command on my repo, just 4 unrelated commits remain. Moreover, these same commits remain when I rerun the command on a new clone of the repo for a different script in the repo. Not able to figure out why this is happening

Comment: @Hashken:  I think the approach in this answer is correct.  We will need more information to understand why it is not working for you.  Which files remain on your master branch after running this?  Which files are modified by the remaining commits?

Comment: I did test this against a local repository and it seemed to work as intended.  If you can share your repository I'm happy to take a look, but otherwise it Works For Me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: The initial commit which added all the files is left. The next two commits touch other scripts. The final commit touches .gitignore. Now in the repo only .gitignore file is present. No other files are present. This is surprising considering that none of the commits remove the other script files.

Comment: @Hashken:  Try to use the filter command I gave in the comment -- it is less susceptible to things like spaces in the file names, and deals correctly with file names starting with a dot.  You might need to add `|| true` to the end of the command to mask any-non-zero exit codes.

Comment: @larsks: Your filter command will never delete `.gitignore` and similar files.  Moreover, if the `ls | grep` returns nothing, the command becomes invalid (just `rm -rf` without further argument), resulting in commits that only change `myscript.sh` being skipped.

Comment: That absolutely true.  This was meant to demonstrate the concept, not work in production :)